# I'm on an EEA FP. Can my spouse who's an EEA citizen travel out of the country while I stay in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, family

Can my spouse (EEA citizen) travel out of the UK while I stay in the UK? I hold an EEA Family Permit.

Comment: When you say travel, do you mean a few weeks vacation or do you mean your spouse would reside elsewhere long-term?

Comment: she would be away for 3 weeks. that's it

Comment: That's certainly not breaking the spirit of the EU rules.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, no, you are not supposed to benefit from freedom of movement in the UK while your wife is outside the UK, but I suspect that a court would draw a distinction between visitors and residents.  If you and your wife have established your residence in the UK, then her temporary absence should not deprive you of the right to remain in the UK.  If you are visiting the UK temporarily, however, and she leaves, then you should probably also leave.

Comment: well, I do work in the UK and we're renting an apartment. although we've been in the UK since February 2018

Comment: I doubt you have much to worry about. What document did you show your employer to demonstrate your authorization to work?  How long will your wife be away?

Comment: she will be away for three weeks